# Match one value if another value does not exist on any lines

Tags: .net, regex

I am looking to match (true or false) on a specific value, if another value does not exist in the entire string, on any line. For example, if I had the following string:

> Red Orange Blue Black
>   Brown Pink Cyan White
>   Yellow

I want to match on "Blue" only if "Yellow" does not exist. Keeping in mind the colors within the string could be in any order.

I have searched everywhere with no luck, and I am assuming this means it may not be possible. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? It's a simple task in most languages using normal string-related functions. Also, there are many different regex dialects, and they all vary significantly in functionality and syntax. What specific dialect are you using?

Comment: Essentially just trying to avoid new development at all costs. Our regex patterns are stored in a database and a match signifies "true" for a specific service being present. The problem is 'Blue' by itself means one specific service, where  'Blue' and 'Yellow' together mean another separate service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead for Yellow anchored to start:

```
^(?s)(?!.*Yellow)(.*)(Blue)
```

The input before Blue is in group 1. If you need it, Blue is in group 2.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your response! I realized that I did not require to look for yellow on multiple lines, so this solves my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: @Oomptz I added the DOTALL flag to handle multiline input

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
/(?!.*Yellow)Blue/i
```

See Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7aSWz7/1

Comment: While this works, we do encourage to add an explanation of why it works.

Comment: See [Is "Try this" good practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196191/172661) for a discussion of why you should *not* say *try this* without an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works, but only if yellow comes after blue, and is on the same line as blue. For example:

'Red Orange Yellow Blue Black Brown Pink Cyan White' will still match on Blue.